# Will running the same script multiple times with a rand() call return different values?

Tags: php

I have a script that calls the `rand` function:

```
<?php
echo rand(0, 9);
?>
```

If I run this script multiple times, will I get different numbers out, or will it always be the same? In other words, does PHP seed `rand` automatically?

Comment: Er. Can you rephrase that? I have no idea what you're asking

Comment: That doesn't make sense. Try to rewrite your post and to give us some sample code.

Comment: My hovercraft is full of eels.

Comment: by rand method a number print, but when it will refresh the new number print out on old number.
<div id="num"><?rand(0,9)?></div>

Comment: @paxdiablo: You sir have just made my entire day. Not shitting you.

Comment: @aamir Amazingly, I think I get what you're asking from that comment. I edited your question; if I misunderstood you please revise it

Comment: If you simply ran that, you would get your answer faster than typing it in SO :)

Answer (score 2):

Before version 4.2.0, it will output the same value every time; you're supposed to call [`srand()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.srand.php) to seed it. Starting with 4.2.0, the random number generator is seeded automatically (see the [`rand()` changelog](https://www.php.net/rand)), so you'll get different outputs every time you run the script

Comment: +1 for understanding the question :-) You can still use srand manually if you want to seed the RNG with the same number, i.e. for debug purposes, or if you don't trust PHPs builtin seeding algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

*YES!* you can get the exact number between 0-9 twice in a row.  Whatever you're asking, you'll find it in [PHP's rand() manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php).